# Push up the layout when Keypad is enabled

Tags: android, tabs, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-keypad

I am using Collapsing ToolBar and Tab to make this layout. When the EditText cursor is enabled the entire activity has to be pushed up. Even here I used the same working code which is working good in an another app without Collapsing ToolBar. But here it is missed to work. Please help me.

This is the code that I used in another activity which is working good.

```
  getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the WindowManager documentation:

SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN

Adjustment option for softInputMode: set to have a window pan when an input method is shown, **so it doesn't need to deal with resizing but just panned** by the framework to ensure the current input focus is visible.

Try setting the soft input mode to only WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: Okay Let me check @Veselin Todorov